# jQuery :not() Selector iOS5 compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, safari

I am using the following block of **jQuery** in my clients wordpress blog:

```
  jQuery(this)
      .children(":not('.previewTitle, .previewBody')")
      .fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity, function(){
      //some code
});
```

This code fades the parent container (this), but not the two inner containers `.previewTitle` and `.previewBody` as I would like. This code works in all major browser versions except iOS (5) Safari - does anyone have any idea why ***iOS*** has beef with me?

Thanks!

EDIT: Ive checked your test code over a few times, but I really cannot see a difference. Here is my full code:

```
jQuery(thumbs).hover(
            function(){
                jQuery(this).children(":not(.previewTitle, .previewBody)").fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity, function(){
                    //Display Preview Body once faded in
                    strId = jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id'); //Get parent DIV ID
                    jQuery('#previewTitle' + strId.substr(9)).show();
                    jQuery('#previewBody' + strId.substr(9)).show();
                });
            },
            function(){
                // Only fade out if the user hasn't clicked the thumb
                if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) 
                {
                    //Fade out of thumbnail..
                    jQuery(this).children(":not(.previewTitle, .previewBody)").fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity, function(){
                        //Hide Preview Body once faded out
                        strId = jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id'); //Get parent DIV ID
                        jQuery('#previewTitle' + strId.substr(9)).hide();
                        jQuery('#previewBody' + strId.substr(9)).hide();
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't put the argument to `:not` in quotes, just:

```
jQuery(this).children(":not(.previewTitle, .previewBody)").fadeTo(....
//            no quote ----^              no quote ----^
```

`:not` accepts *a selector*, not a string. I'm intrigued it works on other browsers with the quotes...

Other than that, it should work. It works for me on iOS 4.3.2 (my wife's iPad): [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/anufer) | [source](http://jsbin.com/anufer/edit)

HTML:

```
<p>Click anywhere in the shaded container:</p>
<div id="container">
  <p>Child that will fade</p>
  <p>Another that will fade</p>
  <p class="previewTitle">previewTitle - won't fade</p>
  <p>Another that will</p>
  <p class="previewBody">previewBody - won't fade</p>
  <p>Another that will</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#container").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .children(":not('.previewTitle, .previewBody')")
      .fadeTo("slow", "0.2");
  });

});
```

...but I don't have iOS 5 handy to test.

---

Side note:

> This code fades the parent container (this), but not the two inner containers `.previewTitle` and `.previewBody` as I would like.

The code you've quoted doesn't fade the parent container at all. It fades all of its *children* except the two listed. That's not the same thing.

Comment: @Matt if you just put a single class in the `:not` selector does it work ? and have you tried using `.not()` instead ?

Comment: @Matt: Without the quotes? That's odd.

Comment: @Matt: Works for me with both: http://jsbin.com/anufer Tested it on my wife's iPad 2, but it only has iOS 4.3.5. If that link doesn't work for you on iOS 5, sounds like a bug somewhere (in jQuery, in WebKit, dunno).

Comment: @T.J Must be an iOS5 thing then :(

Comment: @T.J your link does work correctly on my iPad! I had best recheck my code

Comment: jQuery actually does allow you to quote the argument to `:not()`, but I haven't the slightest clue why. I've posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-jquerys-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments