# Why do functional pseudos such as :not() and :has() allow quoted arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

Apparently, as I've discovered while commenting on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472110/jquery-get-the-last-tr-with-a-th/12472203#12472203), jQuery (rather its underlying selector engine [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com)) lets you quote the argument to the `:not()` selector as well as the `:has()` selector. [To wit](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bRE9u):

```
$('div:not("span")')
$('span:has("span")')
```

In the [Selectors standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors), quotes are always representative of a string and never of a selector or a keyword, so quoting the argument to `:not()` is always invalid. [This will not change in Selectors 4.](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation)

You can also see that it's non-standard syntax by adding an [unsupported CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child) such as `:nth-last-child(1)` [causing the selector to fail completely](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bRE9u/1):

```
$('div:not("span"):nth-last-child(1)')
$('span:has("span"):nth-last-child(1)')
```

Is there any good reason, technical or otherwise, for allowing quotes here? The only possibilities that come to mind are:

- Consistency with `:contains()` which allows both quoted and unquoted arguments, as seen in [the old Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors). Except `:contains()` accepts strings/keywords, not selectors...
- Consistency with the implementation of custom pseudos using `$.expr[':']`, which always allows quoted and unquoted arguments.
- Consistency and ease of porting to their method counterparts `.not()` and `.has()` (just remove or split the outer quotes and change colons to periods?).

But I can't find any sources to support or oppose them. In fact, the ability to quote selector arguments itself isn't documented anywhere either, nor does there appear to be any difference between quoting and not quoting the argument:

```
$('div:not(span)')
$('span:has(span)')
```

Comment: This is likely a quirk of [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), not of jQuery itself.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry my example was bad, I think sole purpose of quotes is escaping.

Comment: It's probably for consistency in the implementation of `$.expr[':']`.

Comment: Not an answer, but jQuery says themselves that they *borrow* from the CSS selector spec rather than implement it faithfully.  Maybe John Resig will stop by with an answer.

Comment: @Explosion Pills: True. In that case, they really should change "CSS3 Compliant" on the home page to "CSS3 Compatible" or something similar as well ;)

Comment: Looking at the test suite, I'd say this is nothing that is supposed to work (not a single test for quoted `:not` or `:has`) https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/test/unit/selector.js

Comment: @zzzzBov: Could be a side effect of its implementation too, but why do selectors like `:eq()` and `:nth-child()` explicitly disallow quotes then? Result of another implementation detail?

Comment: @Prinzhorn: No wonder it isn't documented.

Comment: Do any jQuery developers have accounts here? I'm pretty certain they're the only ones likely to be able to post an accurate answer, rather than supposition, which is all anyone not involved could post, I think.

Comment: @David Thomas: I know [John Resig](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6524/john-resig) does, and visits on occasion.

Comment: Presumably it would be considered an abuse of your diamond-powers to contact him and request an answer (assuming that his site-registered contact details aren't public)?

Comment: @David Thomas: That is correct. If he's alright with being contacted to answer questions, he'll probably put up his contact details somewhere public and say that it's OK to do so. Then I won't need to have special powers to ask :)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8.2, `:eq(...)` and the like now accept quotes. From browsing the changelog, this appears to be a side-effect. If curiosity gets the better of me, I may wind up running a `git-bisect` on Sizzle to find out when exactly this happened.

Comment: Okay, I've bisected Sizzle using a phantomjs script. It does indeed appear that support for `:eq("3")` was added as a side-effect of a bugfix for [a bugfix for `:first` and `:last` selectors](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12303).` Notes added to my answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This isn't specific to `:not(...)` and `:has(...)` selectors- actually, all pseudos
in Sizzle allow for quoted arguments. The pattern for pseudos' arguments
is defined as:

```
pseudos = ":(" + characterEncoding + ")(?:\\((?:(['\"])((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?)\\2|([^()[\\]]*|(?:(?:" + attributes + ")|[^:]|\\\\.)*|.*))\\)|)"
```

Which can be found on line [`91` of `sizzle.js` as of `831c9c48...`](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/831c9c489ef90134436449b5c732f93f0a0b29bb/sizzle.js#L91)

Let's add some indentation to that, to make it a bit more readable.
Unfortunately, this is still a regexp, so "a bit more readable" still
leaves a lot to be desired:

```
pseudos = (
    ":(" + characterEncoding + ")" +
    "(?:" +
    "\\(" + // literal open-paren
        "(?:" +

                "(['\"])" + // literal open-quote
                    "((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?)" + // handle backslash escaping
                "\\2" + // close-quote

            "|" + // - OR -

                "(" +
                    "[^()[\\]]*" +
                    "|" +
                    "(?:" +
                        "(?:" + attributes + ")" +
                        "|" +
                        "[^:]" +
                        "|" +
                        "\\\\." +
                    ")*" +
                    "|" +
                    ".*" +
                ")" +

        ")" +
    "\\)" + // literal close-paren
    "|" + // ie, 'or nothing'
")"
);
```

The main take-away from this is: either single or double-quotes can be
used around the argument in a pseudo-attribute. Backslash escaping is
properly handled, and so any arbitrary string could be passed in as an
argument. Note that the "string" part winds up in the same match index
as the "selector" part in the above regexp; so, in short, that is why
they are treated equally: because the `pseudos` pattern does not
distinguish between the two. **edit:** as of jQuery 1.8.2, arguments
with and without quotes are more-explicitly equivalent. I cannot seem
to find this code in the jQuery git repository [help would be appreciated], but [the version of
1.8.2 hosted by google, having the sha1sum of a0f48b6ad5322b35383ffcb6e2fa779b8a5fcffc](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js), has a
`"PSEUDO":` function on line `4206`, which does explicitly detect a
difference between "quoted" and "unquoted" arguments, and ensures they
both wind up in the same place. This logic does **not** distinguish
between the type of pseudo ("positional" or not) which the argument is
for.

As Sizzle uses Javascript strings to kick off the selection process,
there is no distinction between "string" and "selector" when arguments
are passed in to functions. Making that kind of distinction would be
possible, but as far as I am aware, what is actually desired is always
easily determined from the most basic of context (ie: what type of
pseudo is being used), so there is no real reason to make the
distinction. *(please correct in comments if there are any ambiguous
situations which I am unaware of- I'd like to know!)*.

So then, if the lack of distinction between strings and selectors is a
mere implementation detail, why do pseudos such as `:eq(...)` explicitly
reject such selections?

The answer is simple: it doesn't, really. At least, not as of jQuery
1.8.1. [**edit:** as of jQuery 1.8.2, it doesn't at all. The arguments of
"positional" pseudos can be quoted just like anything else. The below
notes regarding the implementation details of 1.8.1 are left as a
historical curiosity]

Functions such as `:eq(...)` are implemented as:

```
"eq": function( elements, argument, not ) {
    var elem = elements.splice( +argument, 1 );
    return not ? elements : elem;
}
```

At the time that `:eq(...)` receives the argument, it is still in the
form of a bare argument (quotes and all). Unlike `:not(...)`, this
argument doesn't go through a `compile(...)` phase. The "rejection" of
the invalid argument is actually due to the shortcut-casting via
`+argument`, which will result in `NaN` for any quoted string (which in
turn, never matches anything). This is yet another implementation
detail, though in this case a "correctly" behaving one *(again, as far
as I am aware. Are there situations where non-numeric arguments to such
functions should in fact match?)*

**edit:** As of jQuery 1.8.2, Things have been refactored somewhat, and
"positional" pseudos no-longer receive the "raw" argument. As a result,
quoted arguments are now accepted in `:eq(...)` and the like. This change
appears to have been a side-effect of another bugfix, as there is no mention of support for quoted arguments in the changelog for [af8206ff..](https://github.com/runphp/sizzle/commit/af8206ff677909e61aec0158443ff74263e6265b), which was intended to fix [an error in handling `:first` and `:last`, jQuery bug #12303](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12303). This commit was found using `git bisect` and [a relatively simple phantomjs script](https://gist.github.com/3780200). It is notable that after the Sizzle rewrite in [e89d06c4..](https://github.com/runphp/sizzle/commit/e89d06c4134ec439e52382acd0e569e97fed7ebc), Sizzle would not merely fail silently for selectors such as `:eq("3")`, it would actually throw an exception. That should be taken as yet more evidence that `:eq("3")` support is not intended behaviour.

There are indeed rationales regarding custom filters, whose arguments
could in some cases be thought of as strings, and sometimes as
selectors, no matter what they superficially look like, depending on
the method in which they are evaluated... but that much is approaching
the pedantic. It should suffice to say that not having a distinction
at the least makes things simpler when calling functions which, no
matter what they may represent, expect a string representation.

In short, the whole situation can be thought of as an implementation
detail, and is rooted in the fact that selectors are passed around as
strings in the first place (how else would you get them into Sizzle?).

Comment: Haven't you heard of [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)? Or maybe it's just me and Python...

Comment: +1 for taking the time to format the regex and try explaining it (which is a hell of a task). The bounty is yours for the taking.

Comment: I think I actually need to step through it all again. Your comment prompted me to give it another glance, and I think I may have mis-read, despite all my formatting efforts. I also haven't actually stepped through the tokenization process since jQuery 1.8.2 was released, so I really ought to make sure the reasoning is still accurate.

Comment: @YatharthROCK: I'm not sure what the mention of raw strings is meant to be in reference to. Can you expand on your meaning? If you mean that I should have used an alternative to `"\\("`, etc, in the above: the intent was to mimic exactly the content of the original regex string. The only change which I made to it was to split and re-indent the components (in this way, it should be easy to find the corresponding point in the original string). Otherwise, I'd probably use PCRE /x syntax to simply show an equivalent regex, rather than the "same one".

Comment: Raw strings are strings that are interpreted exactly as they are typed — there's no need to escape characters again. They come in handy while dealing with regexes. By [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-the-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments/12503947#comment17106811_12503947], I meant that if you had used raw string, you wouldn't have to escape all the backslashes. It would look a lot better.

Comment: @YatharthROCK: JavaScript has no syntax like Python's raw strings or C#'s verbatim strings.

Comment: @BoltClock Ohh... I didn't know. I actually thought the code here was just pseudo-code. Didn't realize the question was about jQuery...