# Jquery :NOT Selector Usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('body:not(selector)').fadeTo(100,0.3);
```

how can we do this selection's opencity like 0.3;
i am using this not working right now

```
$('body:not(".myCLASS")').fadeTo(400,0.1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "how can we do this selection's opencity like 0.3" but I'll add my 5 cents fixing the selector

```
$('body :not(.myCLASS)')
```

Body element doesn't make a lot of sense here. You could use better container like a  `div` or just remove body from there.

```
$(':not(.myCLASS)')
```

If you happen to have a container to restric the search, you could do

```
$('#myContainerId :not(.myCLASS)')
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to all elements, do not specify `body`:

```
$(":not(.myCLASS)").fadeTo(100, 0.3);
```

However, it would be more efficient to only match the top-level elements you want to fade instead of all of them (fading an ancestor element will affect its descendants). Maybe something like:

```
$("div:not(.myCLASS)").fadeTo(100, 0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code:

```
$('body :not(.myCLASS)').fadeTo(400,0.1);
```

**Update**

Just updated the call, check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mHVA5/

Comment: <body>
<div class="myCLASS"> </div>
</body>

$('body:not(.myCLASS)').fadeTo(400,0.1);
 THis isint working

Comment: The quotes end up being not relevant here, even though IMO they should be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-the-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments