# How can I exclude part of the DOM to be parsed from Jquery Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want a part of my page not to be parsed by the jQuery Selector.

In the example below, is there a way to get all the ".module" elements but exclude the one under the div which has the class "exclude" ?

Moreover, can we do with Jquery something like "please do not parse this area".
For example, I have a page which has a div(#huge) with a HUGE html content, is there a way for Jquery to ignore this div(#huge) ?

For example, I have this structure:

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="exclude">
    <div class="module"></div>
    <!-- HERE HUGE HTML -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="module"></div>
    <div class="module"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't parse, it searches. If your query are well designed, the #huge div isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$modules = $('div:not(".exclude") > .module');
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector

Comment: Drop the quotes inside the `:not()`, they're not needed (even though they're allowed [for some weird reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-the-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments)) and leaving them out can improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

In your precise case, the key is to look only in the right divs.

You would start by making the searchable collection

```
var $good = $('#page>div:not(.exclude)');
```

And all your queries would be built as `$(yourquery, $good)` :

```
var $mymodules = $('.module', $good);
```

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/phtkx/)

Note that when looking for an element by its id, it still would be more efficient to use `$('#theid')` rather than `$('#theid', $good)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$modulesNotTheHugeOne = $(".module").not("#huge");
```

selects all with class `module` but not the one with id `huge`

http://api.jquery.com/not/