# JQuery selector: Select elements without an iframe as a child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to delete all the elements having an iframe as a child.
For example, if I want to delete all the DIVs without an iframe as a child:

```
$("div :not(iframe)").remove();
```

But it doesn't work... What would be the correct instruction?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `:not` and `:has`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xRHwf/1/)**

```
$("div:not(:has(iframe))").remove();
```

Comment: @Royi Namir: Why? It's an element, not a string.

Comment: @user2595583: Yeah it's strange, but I posted a question exploring that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-the-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments

Comment: @BoltClock according to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/has/#has-selector) the argument should be a string. just like you do $("iframe") and not $(iframe)

Comment: @Royi Namir: Ah, you're confusing the [`.has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has) with the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete all the elements having an iframe as a child

I always use a filter:

```
$('div').filter(function(i,el) {
    return $(el).find('iframe').length;
}).remove();
```

to do the opposite:

```
$('div').filter(function(i,el) {
    return !$(el).find('iframe').length;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $divsWithoutIframeChilds = $('div').filter(function(i, el){
    return $(el).find('iframe').length < 1;
});

$divsWithoutIframeChilds.remove();
```