# Not a valid selector error while porting from jQuery to Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, zepto, selectors-api

I am trying to use Zepto in jQuery's place for vex.js plugin.

```
 ".vex:not(".vex-closing") .vex-content"
```

I am getting below error, while performing above selector.

```
 error performing selector: ".vex:not(".vex-closing") .vex-content" zepto.min.js:3
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.vex:not(".vex-closing") .vex-content' is not a valid selector.
```

How can I fix this issue.

Here is the code extracted from vex.js

```
 getAllVexes: function() { 
    return $("." + vex.baseClassNames.vex + ":not(\"." + vex.baseClassNames.closing + "\") ." + vex.baseClassNames.content);
 }
```

Comment: @adeneo: I think that's a problem with the error message rather than the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes aren't normally allowed in the `:not()` selector, since it accepts a selector, not a string. For whatever reason, though, [quotes *are* allowed in jQuery/Sizzle's implementation of `:not()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-functional-pseudos-such-as-not-and-has-allow-quoted-arguments).

You should remove the `\"` marks from your selector string for it to work in `document.querySelectorAll()` (which Zepto appears to call directly, and use exclusively for selector matching — correct me if I'm wrong):

```
return $("." + vex.baseClassNames.vex + ":not(." + vex.baseClassNames.closing + ") ." + vex.baseClassNames.content);
```

This will result in a selector like `.vex:not(.vex-closing) .vex-content`, which is a valid CSS selector.